# What is perl symbol =~

Tags: regex, perl, shell, scripting

I am using someone else's text parsing perl code and I'd like to make some modifications. Could someone explain what =~ symbol is doing?

```
$xmlfile =~ s/value="{(.*?)}"/'value="'.&subst($1).'"'/ge;
```

EDIT:

So I found this thread that explains part of the regex string.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=24640

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: do you understand the rest of the line?

Comment: Tip: you can search for funky syntax on this site. Use the search string `[perl] "=~"` and you'd have had your answer.

Comment: @Thilo Not really. I understand that it is doing some kind of string matching and runs subst() function on the matched string, but I don't really understand the details. Explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, matching, substitution, or transliteration act on `$_`; to use them on another variable, the binding operator `=~` is used.  In your case, the variable the substitution will be performed on is `$xmlfile`.

Comment: So is $xmlfile passed into $1? Or whatever is matched by s/value="{(.*?)}" is passed into $1?

Comment: `$1` is what is captured by the `(.*?)` so is what is found inside the curly braces.  $xmlfile is the string it will be looking through and substituting in.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators):

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match. Certain operations search or modify the string $_ by default. This operator makes that kind of operation work on some other string. The right argument is a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration. The left argument is what is supposed to be searched, substituted, or transliterated instead of the default $_.